# .NET thread creation fails with OutOfMemoryException on a large multicore system

Tags: c#, .net

While running a multi-process (not multi-threaded) number crunching application on a 128-core system with 2 TB of physical memory (RAM).

System specs:

- .NET Framework 4.8
- Windows Server 2019
- AMD machine with 2 sockets * 64 cores each

Application setup looks more or less like this:

- Master node running on a different machine receives workload
- Master node divides workload into 128 equal-sized tasks
- 128 processes get spun up simultaneously on the 128-core system, each processing their own task
- Each worker process runs only 1 thread doing the actual number crunching. This thread is not the main/entry point of the worker process, but is created shortly after startup.

This works ok for up to around ~100 worker processes. Anything higher than that will start workers to fail during initialization of the number crunching thread with this error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Threading.Thread.Start(Object parameter)
```

Obviously this is on a production system running client workloads so it's not easy to just try stuff out on that machine. I'm looking for any pointers or advice on what might cause thread creation to fail in this setup. Given 1MB stack space per thread I would not expect actually running out of memory to be a problem here.

Some thoughts:

- Some other resource besides memory is being exhausted, but i have no idea what it could be
- Each worker process is creating way more threads than i'd hope for. For example this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=net-8.0 mentions "By default, the minimum number of threads is set to the processor count." Which would suggest 128*128 threads being created in this scenario. Not good, but still not hitting a 2TB memory footprint by itself.
- Some kind of memory fragmentation is going on, but even then i'd be hard-pressed to believe an 1MB block is nowhere to be found.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: interesting; any particular reason you're spinning up a process per chunk? it feels like this could be partitioned inside a single process, just using a dedicated thread per chunk, no? that would allow a lot of shared savings...

Comment: It's relatively old app, basically. Some 15+ years, and it was never written with threading in mind. A rewrite would be a major undertaking, and not to say without risk ;)

Comment: Are you sure workers are completely independent? Nothing that would cause workers to require more stack space depending on how many other workers are running? If it is not to much work you might want to try updating to a later .net version. I believe there are some fixes specifically for huge multi core systems.

Comment: There is also the cost of JITting the code for so many processes: JITting takes time, and the memory is not shareable between processes. This is another reason why a shared process would be ideal. If it's actually a .NET library I can't imagine multi-threading would be that difficult, unless there's lots of shared `static` state. Just create a new entrypoint object for each thread and run it separately as you are already doing.

Comment: @JonasH yes, workers are independent. Even so, it's not a stack overflow exception. The error always occurs at thread creation time. We're already in the process of moving to .NET 6 (or 8), but we'll have to maintain the .net 4.8 version for the foreseeable future, too.

Comment: @Charlieface jup, lot of static state unfortunately.

Comment: any chance the exe is running in 32-bit mode? (this used to be the default for "Any CPU") - you can check `Environment.Is64BitProcess` to be sure

Comment: @Marc Gravell definately 64-bit.

Comment: @everyone I get that the current setup might not be ideal and that a multi-threaded solution, possibly on .NET Core, would be preferable, but that's unfortunately not a viable short-term option. On the other hand, I don't see any reason why a multi-processing solution on .NET 4.8 cannot work, either.

Comment: You are likely to run out of kernel memory pool in this scenario.  [This tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-poolmon-to-find-a-kernel-mode-memory-leak) is the top google hit, [this Q+A](https://superuser.com/questions/896026/how-to-increase-the-kernel-memory) is the top hit for doing something about it.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks! That's surely something to investigate. Will report back.